# Https Post gives a error 500 on some computers

Tags: delphi, indy, idhttp

I'm using Delphi XE6 and Indy 10.6.0.5122.

I make a POST to my own web server and it works fine on many computers including my own, but it does not work on some and I can't find out why. The ones it doesn't work on give a return error of 500 "internal server error".

Could it be that the computers that are running my program, don't have the same SSL DLLs?

```pascal
function TMainForm.SendSMStoServer(JsonStr:String): boolean;
var
  IdHTTP2: TIdHTTP;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL3: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  url:String;
  JsonToSend: TStringStream;
  valid:Boolean;
begin
  Try
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL3 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
    IdHTTP2 := TIdHTTP.Create;
    IdHTTP2.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)';
    IdHTTP2.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    IdHTTP2.Request.BasicAuthentication := true;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL3.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
    IdHTTP2.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL3;
    IdHTTP2.HandleRedirects := False;
    JsonToSend := TStringStream.Create(JsonStr);
    valid:=true;
    url:='https://myserver.com?password=xxxxxx&user=xxxxxx';
               
    try
      IdHTTP2.Post(url, JsonToSend);                          
    except
      on E:Exception do
      begin
        SaveToFile(SmsText,JsonStr,E.Message);
        memo1.Lines.Add('To Myserver ' + E.Classname + ': ' + E.Message);
        valid := False;
      end;
    end;
  Finally
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL3.Free;
    IdHTTP2.Free;
    JsonToSend.Free;
  End;
         
  Return := valid;
end;
```

Comment: Unlikely to be DLLs otherwise you'd be getting SSL exceptions rather than 500 errors. Are all the computers using the same content, i.e. `JsonStr`, `username`, and `password`?

Comment: @Ranky "*Unlikely to be DLLs otherwise you'd be getting SSL exceptions rather than 500 errors*" - typically true, although there are some web servers that do allow ignorable mistakes in the SSL/TLS handshake so it can still establish an encrypted channel with the client, and then will immediately send an HTTP error because of those mistakes and not process the client's HTTP request. But this is pretty rare, I think.

Comment: @KimHJ Unless the HTTP 500 error contains a body describing the actual error, the only way you are going to troubleshoot this is to debug the server, or review its logs (if it logs the error at all). Assuming the JSON and other data are accurate, the first thing I would suggest you do is try a different `UserAgent` value that mimics a real web browser, as some web servers do fail on Indy's default `UserAgent`.

Comment: @KimHJ Also, "*10.6.0.5122*" is a VERY old version of Indy (~6 years), you really need to upgrade to the [latest version on GitHub](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/), which is currently 10.6.2.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau What would you suggest to use for UserAgent? I will update to the latest version. Thanks.

Comment: @KimHJ Use whatever `UserAgent` you want, as long as it looks like a real web browser User-Agent and not Indy's default User-Agent.  There are plenty of web sites that explain how a User-Agent is formatted, and provide lists of known User-Agent values?